# A annotation on the volley note to avoid leaking

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-volley, leakcanary

The code on the CacheDispatcher is as below. And focus on that release previous request object to avoid leaking request object when mQueue is drained.
I do not know why. Can anyone tell me the reason? 
Thanks in advance.

```
java
Request<?> request;
while (true) {
    // release previous request object to avoid leaking request object when mQueue is drained.
    request = null;
    try {
        // Take a request from the queue.
        request = mCacheQueue.take();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // We may have been interrupted because it was time to quit.
        if (mQuit) {
            return;
        }
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request = mCacheQueue.take();` is a blocking call so when the queue is empty(drained) we will still keep reference of the old request while waiting if we didn't do `request = null;`

this however is not the best way to achieve this behavior and it was changed in the new Volley code to :

```
while (true) {
            try {
                // Get a request from the cache triage queue, blocking until
                // at least one is available.
                final Request<?> request = mCacheQueue.take();
```

Comment: Understanded.Thanks for your answer.